# Не показывает заголовки PageTabStrip?

Tags: java, android

Всем привет. Взял простой пример реализации viewPager [отсюда.](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html)

Работает все нормально но я подключил pagerTabStrip для показа заголовки страницы, и у меня следующая проблема. При перво запуске заголовки не показываются.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того как я переверну страницу заголовки показываются.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема? Ниже скидываю листинг.

Activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            >
            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/pagerTabStrip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top">
            </android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip>
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Adapter ViewPager

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    static final int PAGE_COUNT = 4;
    ArrayList<String> PageTitle = new ArrayList<String >();
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        PageTitle.add("Русские артисты");
        PageTitle.add("Зарубежные артисты");
        PageTitle.add("Поиск");
        PageTitle.add("Добавить артиста");
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return PageTitle.get(position);
    }
}
```

Фрагменты

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {


    static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";

    int pageNumber;
    int backColor;

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, null);

        TextView tvPage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPage);
        tvPage.setText("Page " + pageNumber);


        return view;
    }


}
```

MainActivity

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(2);
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Сам столкнулся с этой проблемой. Долго не мог понять причину и никак не мог найти решение. Оказалось это баг гугла: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183127 Там же предложили временное решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379050/how-can-we-work-around-the-blank-title-in-pagertitlestrip-and-pagertabstrip/32379051#32379051

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте сначала присваивать OnPageChangeListener и только потом выбирать текущий элемент

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(...);
pager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

Также рассмотрите вариант использования [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)

**UPD:**

В TabLayout можно задать `app:tabMode="scrollable"`. Таким образом, если заголовки в табах не влезают на экран они уходят за его края и их можно скроллить.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    ...
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Даже если я удалю эту строчку ничего не происходит. TabLayout отпадает, так как у меня будет много вкладок, с длинным текстом, не помещается!

Comment: Про TabLayout и табы с длинным текстом см дополнение в моём ответе.

Comment: а вот за это СПАСИБО!)))

Answer (score 1):

Мою проблему с отображением заголовков впервые созданого `activity` с **`ViewPager`** решил такой способ:

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
pager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

pager.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        pager.setCurrentItem(0, false);
        pager.setCurrentItem(2, false);
        pager.postInvalidate();
    }
});

pager.setCurrentItem(2);

pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```